# I want users to see a line break in my <textarea> instead of a <br>

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, onkeyup

When I type `br` into my `<textarea>` I really mean:

```
<br>
```

When key 13 (return) is pressed, I insert `br` into the `.message` `<textarea>`. This puts a nice line break in my `<div>` with the class `.M`.

My problem is that the user sees `br` in the `.message` `<textarea>`. I have to put it in there else the `br` wont be added next time a key is pressed.

Here's my code:

```
$('.message').keyup(function(e){
        pos = $('.message').prop("selectionStart");
        start = $('.message').val().substring(0,pos);
        end = $('.message').val().substring(pos);
    //preventers
    if(e.keyCode==222){$('.message').val(msg);$('.M').html(msg);}else{msg = $('.message').val();$('.M').html(msg);}
    //replacers
        if(e.keyCode==13){msg = start+'<br>'+end;$('.message').val(msg);$('.M').html(msg);}else{msg = $('.message').val();$('.M').html(msg);}
    //sweep
    pattern=/'/gi;var illegal=msg.match(pattern);
    if(illegal!==null){illegal=illegal.length;while(illegal>0){msg=msg.replace("'","");msg=msg.replace('"','');$('.M').html(msg);$('.message').val(msg);illegal--;}}
    pattern=/"/gi;var illegal=msg.match(pattern);
    if(illegal!==null){illegal=illegal.length;while(illegal>0){msg=msg.replace("'","");msg=msg.replace('"','');$('.M').html(msg);$('.message').val(msg);illegal--;}}
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea class="message" id="message" value="" maxlength="75"
         style="position:relative;top:1p‌​x;left:5px;resize:none;border:none;background:none;height:17px;width:428px;">
</te‌​xtarea>


<div class="M_" 
     style="position:relative;top:100px;left:0px;height:160px;width:200px;c‌​olor:#000;z-index:2;">
</div>
```

Comment: @SunnyBasra You should edit your question and add your HTML. It makes it easier to read and, thus, easier for people to help come up with an answer.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff - not sure sunny can with 11 rep -- I added it.

Comment: @Hogan Hah! I was just doing the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might reconsider when you perform the replacements.  If you try to do this interactively you are going to have a hard time.  Far better to wait for the submit of the data and only change the data that is being sent to the server.

Comment: i see what you are thinking but in doing it this way (each time the key is pressed) i am letting the user know (with a sound) that they cannot use the illegal characters. btw: completely off topic.

Comment: You can still sound the bell -- just wait for the submit to do the replace.